# Repeat rows based on field in Pandas

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I am using the *Python Data Analysis Library* and have a data table like it follows:

```
+----------------+
| ID | Frequency |
+----------------+
| AA | 4         |
| BB | 2         |
| CC | 3         |
| DD | 1         |
+----------------+
```

I would like to generate a result table where each original row occurrence has a multiplicity indicated by the `Frequency` field above. The new values for the `Frequency` field should be increasing starting from `1`, finishing with the original frequency value.

```
+----------------+
| ID | Frequency |
+----------------+
| AA | 1         |
| AA | 2         |
| AA | 3         |
| AA | 4         |
| BB | 1         |
| BB | 2         |
| CC | 1         |
| CC | 2         |
| CC | 3         |
| DD | 1         |
+----------------+
```

As I have no idea how start to solve this issue, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I tried to make it more clear what are you trying to achieve. It would also be really helpful in the future if you could show the others how did you try to solve the issue yourself. It does not matter if it does not work, because it shows how you tried to approach the problem and make it easier the others to answer your question. It also shows that you do not only want the others to write code instead of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a built in way to do this; however, I can't find it in the documentation.  The following seems to work for me...

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> d = pd.DataFrame([['AA',4],['BB',3],['CC',2],['DD',1]],columns=['id','frequency'])

>>> k=((' '+d.id)*d.frequency).apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.split(' '))).stack()
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(k[(k.T != '')])

>>> df.reset_index(inplace=True)
>>> df.columns=['l0','frequency','id']

>>> df[['id','frequency']]
   id  frequency
0  AA          1
1  AA          2
2  AA          3
3  AA          4
4  BB          1
5  BB          2
6  BB          3
7  CC          1
8  CC          2
9  DD          1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID":["AA", "BB", "CC", "DD"], "Frequency": [4, 3, 2, 1]})
l = []
for idx, i in df.iterrows():
    x = i["Frequency"]
    while x > 0:
        d = {}
        d.update({"ID":i["ID"], "Frequency":i["Frequency"]-x+1 })
        l.append(d)
        x-=1

ndf = pd.DataFrame(l)
ndf = ndf[["ID", "Frequency"]]
print(ndf)

   ID  Frequency
0  AA          1
1  AA          2
2  AA          3
3  AA          4
4  BB          1
5  BB          2
6  BB          3
7  CC          1
8  CC          2
9  DD          1
```